# Javascript: Drawing rectangle on canvas doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a web application where you can draw a rectangle on a canvas. I use two canvas elements: one for the preview while drawing and another one laying exactly under the other one for drawing it.

The problem I have is that in Internet Explorer, `canvas2.width = canvas2.width` doesn't clear the content of canvas2, which is necessary because for every mousemove the rectangle gets drawn again. I also tried `context2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height)`, but, however, then the preview rectangle doesn't get drawn at all. Try it out on **http://jsfiddle.net/Y389a/2/**

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="600" height="400" onmouseup="return drawLine()" onmousedown="return startLine()"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas, #canvas2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#666666;
    cursor:default !important;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var x; var xStart;
var y; var yStart;
var clicked = false;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.lineCap = "round";

canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
    var rect = canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
    if (clicked) {
        canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
        context2.rect(xStart, yStart, x - xStart, y - yStart);
        context2.stroke();
    }
}, false);

function startLine() {
    context.beginPath();
    xStart = x; yStart = y;
    clicked = true;
}

function drawLine() {
    clicked = false;
    context.rect(xStart, yStart, x - xStart, y - yStart);
    context.stroke();
}
```

**[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/Y389a/2/)**

Comment: I use the latest version, IE11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You are drawing rectangles with `context2.rect` which is a path command.

Path commands are "remembered" by the canvas until a new `context2.beginPath` is issued

Therefore, all your previous rects are being remembered and redrawn when you do `context2.stroke`

**Fix**

Just put context2.beginPath in your mousemove event handler:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/A8ge6/

```
canvas2.addEventListener("mousedown",startLine);
canvas2.addEventListener("mouseup",drawLine);
    canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
        var rect = canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();
        x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
        y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
        if (clicked) {
            canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
            console.log(xStart);

            // add beginPath so previous context2.rect's are dismissed
            context2.beginPath();

            context2.rect(xStart, yStart, x - xStart, y - yStart);
            context2.stroke();
        }
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to stroke a rectangle you can use this version:

```
context2.strokeRect(xStart, yStart, x - xStart, y - yStart);
```

instead of `rect()` + `stroke()`.

This does not add any sub path to the main path but draws directly to canvas. If you need to add other shapes to your path later remember to use `beginPath()` for `rect()` in a similar way as you already do in `startLine()` as `rect()` add a sub-path.

Answer (score 1):

There is Nothing Wrong with the Code and nothing Wrong With IE 9,What you missed is a l'le concept ,

addEventListener() didn't work For IE instead you have to use attachEvent() for it to make your Code run in IE

```
//For your code to work in IE
if (!canvas2.addEventListener) {
canvas2.attachEvent("onclick", CanvasFunction);
}
//for rest of the Browser
else {
canvas2.addEventListener("click", CanvasFunction, false);
}

function CanvasFunction(evt)
{
var rect = canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
    if (clicked) {
        canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
        console.log(xStart);

        // add beginPath so previous context2.rect's are dismissed
        context2.beginPath();

        context2.rect(xStart, yStart, x - xStart, y - yStart);
        context2.stroke();
    }
}
```

Playing with Canvas ,remember IE doesn't support addEventListners ..Enjoy Coding

Comment: I only wanted to know how to make it work on IE 11, but it's also very useful to know how to improve the compatibility to older browsers :)

Comment: This is what you have to do, That AddEventListner You added in your code snippet, it is fine for all other browsers but IE (any version) didn't understand it, so to make your code to work on IE you have to use an alternate attachEvent,Process:is same what i have mentioned Above